# PostGIS clipping raster with the same color band as the original raster

Tags: postgis, raster

I am trying to clip a raster so that the clipped raster would have the same minimum and maximum values for the color band as the original raster.

For example if i clip the raster with this command:

```
create table clipped AS SELECT ST_Clip(rast,ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText ('LINESTRING(424920 7370964, 424920 7371476,425432 7371476,425432  7370964,424920 7370964) ')) ) FROM original;
```

I get the following result:

[image: Picture from QGIS]

So the clipped raster has band minimum value as 0 and maximum value as 20. Instead of that, i want it to be exactly same as the 'original' raster: from 0 to 33. In other words, I want the color of the clipped raster to be same as it is in that area in the 'original' raster.

I am new for PostGIS, but i have tried to find an answer for a while to this question but i haven't found anything. I have tried the functions like ST_Reclass but with no success. What is the proper way to do this with PostGIS?

Comment: Just copy the same style and you will see the same colors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how do you do that in PostGIS? I want to do it in PostGIS query, not in QGIS. That picture from QGIS-editor is just for visualizing the problem.

Comment: ST_Clip does not alter the values. The style (ramp) used in QGIS let you believe that. Try to use ST_Value in a SQL query to check.

Comment: Ok i noticed that i did not specify my problem good enough.Yes, but in my case after the clipping i want to make a picture from the clipped raster (with ST_AsPNG and ST_ColorMap) and analyze the picture band color values (black to white). The problem is that after making the png, the picture is just like in that QGIS-picture example i posted above. I want the band colors to match the 'orginal' band colors, because i want analyze the png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to ST_ReClass() the values of your raster before passing it to ST_AsPNG() so that it looks the same as the first raster. This will not affect the values stored in the raster in the database but will definitely produce a very different image.